# Run PHP CS fixer with GrumPHP

Tags: php, symfony, phpcs

I'm using GrumPhp to sniff my commit in my symfony project: https://github.com/phpro/grumphp

Here is my config:

```
parameters:
    git_dir: .
    bin_dir: vendor/bin
    tasks:
        phpcsfixer:
            config_file: ~
            config: sf23
            fixers: [psr2, symfony, indentation]
            level: psr2
            verbose: true
```

My question is:

Is there a way for **Grumphp** to automatically run `php-cs-fixer` when I commiting?

Comment: What is your output if you run ./vendor/bin/grumphp run?

Comment: Checkout https://adapttive.com/blog/grumphp-in-magento-2

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is!
https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/blob/master/doc/tasks.md

Since your post is a bit older here is the new updated doc, but you can still use version one! https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/blob/master/doc/tasks/php_cs_fixer2.md

You could try out this configuration but it's phpcsfixer version2!:

```
# grumphp.yml
parameters:
    bin_dir: "./vendor/bin"
    git_dir: "."
    hooks_dir: ~
    hooks_preset: local
    stop_on_failure: false
    ignore_unstaged_changes: false
    process_async_limit: 10
    process_async_wait: 1000
    process_timeout: 60
    ascii:
        failed: grumphp-grumpy.txt
        succeeded: grumphp-happy.txt
    tasks:
        phpcsfixer2:
        allow_risky: false
        cache_file: ~
        config: ~
        rules: ['@Symfony']
        using_cache: true
        path_mode: ~
        verbose: true
```

Your config looks fine, what's the output ?
Do you have the cs fixer installed and configured the grumPHP config to the path of your CS fixer?
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#usage

Answer (score 1):

GrumPHP always run `php-cs-fixer` with the `--dry-run` argument and this behavior is not configurable. You can read why here: https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/issues/110

*But* there's a way to automatically run `php-cs-fixer`: you have to install [GrumPHP Extra Tasks](https://github.com/wearejust/grumphp-extra-tasks) and replace `phpcsfixer2` with `php_cs_auto_fixerv2` in your "grumpphp.yml" file.

Be aware that as of today GrumPHP Extra Tasks is not compatible with the latest version of GrumPHP but up to 0.17.2.